# Prevent Navigation Component Rendering on Single Route but Render on every other Route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

So I have a single Route `/reminder`, where I do not want my `Navigation` component, but I want the `Navigation` component to render on every other Route and I'm not sure how to go about this?

This is my `App.js` where I am using `react-router-dom` for my routing.

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Navigation from "./components/navigation/Navigation";
import Reminder from "./components/reminder/Reminder ";

const App = () => {

  return (
    <>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/reminder" component={Reminder} exact />
      </Switch>
      <Navigation />
      <MainContent>
        <Router>
          <Route path={"/"} component={Dashboard} exact />
        </Router>
      </MainContent>
    </>
  );
}
```

I had a look around for similar issues, but it's mostly for authenticated pages, this isn't for an authenticated page.

I don't want to go down the route of having to add the `Navigation` component into each of my 21 current routes, it seems like there should a better method?

With my current code above, it renders the `Reminder` component but still renders the `Navigation` component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the match data using a [custom hook from react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/useroutematch). All you need to do is

```
import { useRouteMatch } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  let match = useRouteMatch("/reminder");

  // Do whatever you want with the match...
  return (
<>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/reminder" component={Reminder} exact />
  </Switch>
  {!match && <Navigation />} <---Conditional rendering
  <MainContent>
    <Router>
      <Route path={"/"} component={Dashboard} exact />
    </Router>
  </MainContent>
</>
  );
    }
```

Also, while I didn't change this in your example, it's not generally a good idea to have a route outside of the router component. I'm actually a little surprised react-router-dom didn't throw an error for you.